# Changing margin size with \addtolength command

Tags: margins

I am trying to make the margin narrower and use the command
`\addtolength{\hoffset}{-0.5cm} and \addtolength{\voffset}{-0.5cm}`

I have used the package `calc`, but there is still an error message saying 'Please type another file name for output'

I have tried putting the addtolength command in the preamble and after the `\begin{document}` but none of them work. I am wondering how can I fix this?

So here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{calc}
\title{AAA}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-0.5cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-0.5cm}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
some text
\end{document}
```

Helps are really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why changing the offsets? I'd suggest you to use the `geometry` package to change the page layout.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina. Thanks for the comment. Would you mind showing how to write the associated commands? Thanks.

Comment: @Henry: The [`geometry` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) is well-written with examples on how to write things. If you just want "the margins changed", you need to be more specific. All the margins? ...then `\geometry{margin=1in}`. Only left/right? ...then `\geometry{left=1in,right=5mm}`. Only top/bottom? ...then `\geometry{top=50pt,0.8in}`. ...there's plenty of options.

Answer (score 8):

Using geometry is a very useful as already commented. However, if you would like to use `\addtolength`, then you can do something like this:

```
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-2cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-2cm}
```

As the name implies, `\hoffset` and `\voffset` only change the offset ;-)